# State operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure

Tags: .net, redis, dapr

I am doing a small project using Dapr and state management with .Net 6 following this tutorial https://www.gokhan-gokalp.com/en/building-microservices-by-using-dapr-and-net-with-minimum-effort-01/.
But there is an exception that I dont know how to deal with. Please let me know, any ideas will be so appreciated to me.

When I called this method
[image]

An exception was thrown like this

```
Dapr.DaprException: 'State operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.'

Inner Exception
RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.SocketConnectivitySubchannelTransport.TryConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)")
```

Here is the command running dapr

```
start dapr run --app-id shoppingcartapi --app-port 5001 --dapr-http-port 50001 --components-path "./components" -- dotnet run --project "./Dapr.ShoppingCart/Dapr.ShoppingCart.csproj"
start dapr run --app-id recommendationapi --app-port 6000 --dapr-http-port 50002 --components-path "./components" -- dotnet run --project "./Dapr.Recommendation/Dapr.Recommendation.csproj"
```

Here is the pubsub yaml file

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: eventbus
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
```

and the statestore yaml file

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: redisstore
spec:
  type: state.redis
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
  - name: actorStateStore
    value: "true"
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to *redis* successfully?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If I launch dapr from the command line it works. If I launch it through VS Code it fails

Comment: make sure you use the protocol: http for the service which allow that service's sidecar run

Answer (score 0):

In my Program.cs file, I forgot to add this pipeline `app.MapActorsHandlers();` .
Add this and the problem was gone.